# BigDecimal - unexpected round behaviour

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I think I have found a bug:

```
MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
result = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.004798).round(mathContext); // fails
// result is 0.004798!!! (same value)
```

I had to use the following alternative:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.004798);
BigDecimal new_divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(1, 5);
bigDecimal_array = bigDecimal.divideAndRemainder(new_divisor);
MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
result = bigDecimal.subtract(bigDecimal_array[1], mathContext);
result = result.stripTrailingZeros();
```

This bug (if it is so) is very dangerous in my opinion.

Comment: That value has a precision of 4.

Comment: You don't specify an expected result, but I guess you want `java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(0.004798).setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` (= 0.00480). As an aside, given doubles are inherently imprecise, it is better not to use them for creating a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no bug. You're just misunderstanding what "precision" means.

From [`BigDecimal`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

> the total number of digits to return is specified by the MathContext's precision setting; this determines the result's precision. **The digit count starts from the leftmost nonzero digit** of the exact result.

(emphasis mine).

You have 4 digits in this case. So any precision greater then or equal to 4 will have no effect on rounding.

Compare with

```
result = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.004798).round(new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
result ==> 0.00480
```

or with

```
jshell> result = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.004798).round(new MathContext(5, RoundingMode.UP));
result ==> 1.0048
```

Which behave like you expect.